# How to use geowithin in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, geo

I got an unexpected result when using `$geoWithin`,

I've this:

```
perim = 10
center = [35.964734, 5.03952]
```

if i run:

```
list(db.users.find({"adr.cor":{"$geoWithin":{"$center":[center, perim]}}}))
```

I get a result  that contains further coordinates, for example: `[36.743954, 4.365041]` which is further! (at least 400km)
what am i doing bad?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using $center:[longitude,latitude], radius, the radius is measured in radians, so you would have to convert 10 radians to km.

Comment: so this is why when i put a small value i get accurate results^

Comment: sorry, but radians are for angles, and the users will put distance?

Comment: Hi Abdelouahab -- you can convert using:   Radians * radius = arc length.  http://www.regentsprep.org/Regents/math/algtrig/ATM1/arclengthlesson.htm

Comment: so from what i understand, a user cant put only the value of the radius (seach people living in 10 kilometer around?)

Comment: Unfortunately no. To convert distance to radians, you would divide the distance by the radius of the sphere (e.g. the Earth) in the same units as the distance measurement.

The radius of the Earth is approximately 3,959 miles or 6,371
kilometers.
So, you would have

perim = 10/6371

list(db.users.find({"adr.cor":{"$geoWithin":{"$center":[center, perim]}}}))

Comment: ah! so that great! hope mongodb will use that method since mongodb is used only on this  planet :p

Comment: ok, it took m awhile to figure this out, but the arc being referred to is not an arc around the center point, but rather the arc from the center of the earth to a circle projected on the surface of the earth.

Comment: this dident work, i dont know why! maybe it is not the earth perimter that i must use